# How to add tags in asp.net TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, tags, richtextbox

> How can I add tag suggestion in my asp.net text box like in the picture given below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJWyq.png

Comment: What have you tried?  I'll give you a hint-  As your typing it sends an Ajax to another page or service then returns to you the matches.

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript plugin, like tag-it (http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) or TagsInput (http://xoxco.com/projects/code/tagsinput/).
TagIt supports autocomplete...